# How to correctly apply a CSS style to all the images in a div having a specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, xhtml

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="group-item">
    <a href="profile.html">
        <img src="resources/img/icons/projects/wifi.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to set the CSS property of the `img` tag inside the div having `class="group-item"` in this way:

```
.groups-item img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

but it does not work and it is not applied to the previous `img` tag (I used FireBug and I can see that the style is not applied)

Why? What am I missing? How can I correctly apply the style to all the img tags inside the div having `class="group-item"`?

Comment: You have `.groups-item` but use `group-item`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.group-item img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

should work, I removed the s from `groups-` in the css declaration

Comment: Seriously not worth an answer

Comment: Because I edited it before I tested to see what was wrong. Then I commented that it was a spelling mistake instead of answering it was a spelling mistake

Comment: @mplungjan - fair enough, still, you have 50k points, I have 1.5k, I'm just trying to pull myself up a bit being new to the site, so I'll take some low hanging fruit here and there

Answer (score -2):

Problem is in your Class Define

You gave Class name group-item in HTML where as You use .groups-item in CSS.

Use it like

```
.group-item a img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
```